# Including a QT library in another QT project

Tags: c++, qt, libraries

I am trying to include a library I've written in a QT project. I've imported the library to the project, and have included the header files. However, when I try to build the project referencing any of the classes in my library, I get a `LNK2001: unresolved external symbol error` I'm still new to QT and I'm sure there is a simple fix to the mistake I've made, but I'm unable to find it anywhere else.

The .pro file:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = SL-Reporter
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        SLReportMainWindow.cpp \
    ProjectEditorWindow.cpp \
    OptionsWindow.cpp \
    FileManager.cpp \
    Project.cpp

HEADERS  += SLReportMainWindow.h \
    ProjectEditorWindow.h \
    OptionsWindow.h \
    FileManager.h \
    Project.h \
    CPPRTF/ColorOutOfRangeException.h \
    CPPRTF/cpprtf_global.h \
    CPPRTF/Exception.h \
    CPPRTF/InvalidFontException.h \
    CPPRTF/RTFColor.h \
    CPPRTF/RTFDocument.h \
    CPPRTF/RTFFont.h \
    CPPRTF/RTFObject.h \
    CPPRTF/RTFTextElement.h

FORMS    += SLReportMainWindow.ui \
    ProjectEditorWindow.ui \
    OptionsWindow.ui

DISTFILES += \
    ../SL-Compare/SLCompare \
    CPPRTF/CPPRTF.lib \
    CPPRTF/CPPRTFd.lib \
    CPPRTF/CPPRTF.dll

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../CPPRTF/build-CPPRTF-Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_MSVC2015_64bit-Debug/release/ -lCPPRTF
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../CPPRTF/build-CPPRTF-Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_MSVC2015_64bit-Debug/debug/ -lCPPRTF
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../CPPRTF/build-CPPRTF-Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_MSVC2015_64bit-Debug/ -lCPPRTF

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../CPPRTF/CPPRTF
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../CPPRTF/CPPRTF
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `-L$$PWD/../CPPRTF/` and just `CPPRTF/` are pointing to different locations. Check on where you did you create that directory: one level up from current (where your project .pro file is) or in the current directory?

Add to project file:

```
# simpler case
LIBS += -lMyLib
```

And you can specify paths:

```
# adding many paths/libs
LIBS += -LAbsolutePath \
        -L$$PWD/CurDirRelativePath \
        -lMyLib1 \
        -lMyLib2 \
```

And `DISTFILES` variable does not seem need to have *.lib files added. Only *.so for Linux/MacOS and *.dll for Windows we usually add to `DISTFILES`.

The manual [Adding Libraries to projects](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-qmake-libraries.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Qt Creator assistant. Right-click on your project and choose : *Add Library...*   .

After that *External library* and then next to *Library file* youse the browser to add your *.dll*,*.so*,*.dylib*,...

Just choose your OS and click on *Next*, the assistant will make all for you.

Comment: That is how I added the library, however, when I build it won't recognize any of the classes or functions in the library. :(